# How best to manage Redis connections using ServiceStack?

Tags: redis, servicestack, connection-pooling

I work on a few .NET web apps that use Redis heavily for caching along with ServiceStack's Redis client. In all cases I've got Redis running on the same machine. I've used both **BasicRedisClientManager** and **PooledRedisClientManager** (always implemented as singletons) and have had some issues with both approaches.

With **BasicRedisClientManager**, things would work fine for a while, but eventually Redis would start refusing connections. Using netstat we discovered that thousands of TCP connections to the default Redis port were hanging around in TIME_WAIT status.

We then switched to **PooledRedisClientManager**, which seemed to fix the problem immediately. However, not long after, we started noticing occasional CPU spikes that we narrowed down to thread waiting (System.Threading.Monitor.Wait calls) caused by PooledRedisClientManager.GetClient.

In code, we use a get-in-get-out approach (using ServiceStack's handy ExecAs shortcuts) so in general connections are acquired very frequently but held as briefly as possible.

We get a modest amount of traffic but we're no StackExchange, and I can't help but think the ServiceStack client is up to the job and we're just doing something wrong. Is PooledRedisClientManager the correct approach here? Would it be advisable to simply increase the pool size? Or is that likely just masking a problem with our code?

Just looking for general guidance here, I don't have specific code I need help with at this point. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pure and Total Speculation-I've used AppHarbor and had issues with Redis connections being held onto and hitting Redis connection limits. The sites receive basically zero traffic so I speculate it's due to IIS hitting the idle-timeout and shutting down my app and somehow not disposing Redis connections properly. The SS 'RedisClientManagers' do handle closing connections on 'Dispose', though. Again, just speculation, but a few IIS idle-timeouts not disposing connections and a few 'Application_Starts' creating new Redis connections seems a plausible culprit.

Comment: Are you sure your connections are being closed?  Check the CLIENT LIST command using redis-cli

Answer (score 5):

Are you absolutely sure all Redis connections are being disposed?

With ServiceStack, the `Redis`property on `Service` and `ViewPageBase` (if you're using SS Razor) do dispose themselves, but any time you request a connection from the pool yourself you must dispose it yourself.

However, despite this, we recently had issues with our pool being exhausted of all connections, too.  One of my colleagues discovered that there wasn't proper clean up for Razor pages and made a pull request [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/pull/923) - This means that there has only been correct disposal on Razor pages since ServiceStack v4.0.21.  I have not checked if that fix has been back-ported to the v3 branch.

My colleague also added `TrackingRedisClientsManager` that may help you track down the improper disposal.  See [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/6f10ef995de650681f84be6170a2c8585ea4bece/src/ServiceStack.Redis/Support/Diagnostic/TrackingRedisClientsManager.cs)

You can also check the stats of a `PooledRedisClientManager` [by using this helper method](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/1bcfef15c565c9945cc340aa8f9aa8d3a3d01130/src/ServiceStack.Redis/PooledRedisClientManager.cs#L456).  We threw it on a little razor page to check the stats as we feel appropriate) but you could write better code around this to monitor the pool health of specific nodes, too.